How to write Terraform code to add a S3 bucket policy to an existing S3 bucket?
I would like to add S3 bucket policy to an existing S3 bucket with Terraform code. The provider is AWS. As follows is the code.
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"  # Set your desired AWS region
  endpoints {
    s3 = "https://s3.amazonaws.com"
  }                                                                                                   }                                                                                                                                                                                                           data "aws_region" "current" {}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3_bucket_policy" {
  bucket = "abcde-us-east-1"

  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Principal" : "*",
        "Action" : "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:s3:::abcdefg-us-east-1/*",
          "arn:aws:s3:::abcdefg-us-east-1"
        ]
      }
    ]
  })
  depends_on = [data.aws_region.current]
}

I got errors:
│ Error: putting S3 Bucket (abcde-us-east-1) Policy: operation error S3: PutBucketPolicy, https response error StatusCode: 307, RequestID: HJTZDV9QHWNYNTXV, HostID: BjDIyLql/Q32dg0NeRjbty37ezisJNl9Q8YVykL5EQ7YY/RUgvwyHGmS93sW9rBX+NK66wNvTc4=, api error TemporaryRedirect: Please re-send this request to the specified temporary endpoint. Continue to use the original request endpoint for future requests. │ │   with aws_s3_bucket_policy.s3_bucket_policy, │   on main.tf line 18, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3_bucket_policy": │   18: resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3_bucket_policy" {
Note: The existing S3 bucket contains ton of data. I would like to add S3 bucket policy to it without creating an new S3 bucket and copy over data from the existing S3 bucket to new S3 bucket. I can write Terraform code to provision a S3 bucket with bucket policy. The challenge is how to write Terraform code to add S3 bucket policy to an existing S3 bucket?
I tried different version of Terraform code to add a S3 bucket policy to an existing S3 bucket without creating the S3 bucket. I got errors.
Note: There is a similar question on this topic. I tried that solution. It does not work.

Is there any particular reason you need to define the S3 endpoint? Also, why is there a dependency on the data source?

I got no endpoints found error if I did not define s3 endpoints.  There is no dependency on the data source. Do you have idea of how to create a S3 bucket policy for an existing S3 bucket? i.e. create a S3 bucket policy for an existing S3 bucket without provisioning the S3 via Terraform code?

Yup, there is a dependency, depends_on = [data.aws_region.current]. :) The error shouldn't exist if you are configuring your provider the right way.

I understand I did not configure it in correct way. What is the right way to configure it. What kind of code you may write if you add a S3 bucket policy to an existing S3 bucket? I have no clue how to write the code properly.
